# SELinux: Deny access to my custom type for unconfined_t processes

Tags: debian, selinux

SELinux, debian 11, default policy (installed via apt). I created my own type for files. I want these files to be able to be accessed only by certain applications, but not by any other unconfined_t apps (even as root). What is the most simple and reliable way to implement this? Preferably without complicated settings, as close as possible to default policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I created a TE file that implements my task.

I'll leave it here in case it's useful to someone.

The main problem is that if we use `files_type (< our type >)`, then all unconfined processes will automatically get access to these files. So it's enough just not to use `files_type()` macro.

```
policy_module(mytest,1.0)

require {
    type kernel_t;
    type init_t;
    type initrc_t;
    type user_home_dir_t;
    role unconfined_r;
    type unconfined_t;
    attribute exec_type;
}

type mytest_file_t;
type mytest_app_t;

allow mytest_app_t mytest_file_t:file { manage_file_perms relabel_file_perms exec_file_perms quotaon mounton watch };

# mark mytest_app_t as unconfined application
unconfined_domain(mytest_app_t);
application_exec_all(mytest_app_t);
application_signal(mytest_app_t);
files_unconfined(mytest_app_t);

# files
fs_associate(mytest_file_t);
type_transition mytest_app_t user_home_dir_t: file mytest_file_t;

# add to unconfined role
role unconfined_r types { mytest_app_t mytest_file_t};

# allow transition to mytest_app_t only from unconfined, kernel and init
allow {unconfined_t kernel_t init_t initrc_t} mytest_app_t : process {transition siginh rlimitinh noatsecure};

# allow kernel and init apps to work with my files
allow {kernel_t init_t initrc_t} mytest_file_t:file { manage_file_perms relabel_file_perms quotaon mounton watch };

# allow any exec file to be entrypoint to mytest_app (only for demo and test reasons)
allow mytest_app_t exec_type : file {read_file_perms exec_file_perms entrypoint};
```

This configuration introduces two types: `mytest_app_t` and `mytest_file_t`. If the `mytest_app_t` process creates a file in the `user_home_dir_t` folder, then the file will be of type `mytest_file_t`. Access to this file will be denied even to unconfined root processes. Also, config introduces an exception for kernel and init.

To test the concept, you can run the command and create a file at /home/cp/file1.txt in the nano application, manually setting the process type.

```
runcon -t mytest_app_t /usr/bin/nano /home/cp/file1.txt
```

[image]

[image]

Viewing and modifying `mytest_file_t` files is only possible if it comes from the `mytest_app_t` process. Even root cannot see the properties of these files.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. It's best to put command output in the question instead of using photos.